# Obj-C: Checking for memory leaks - how to know when Cocoa objects remove itself from memory

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, memory-leaks

What´s the fastest way of checking when Cocoa classes deallocate under ARC, in my own classes when I want to check for memory problems I put a NSLog in the `- (void) dealloc;` method, so I know when it´s deallocated. But for Obj-C classes like NSArray how do I know when it´s deallocated?. Also with ARC on if I set a class to nil, will it automatically remove itself from memory?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can find out when a class (any class) is deallocated using the Allocations instrument in Instruments. That's the better way to do it. However, it is still possible to override dealloc and log a message under ARC. The difference is that when you override dealloc, you cannot call `[super dealloc]` (the compiler handles that for you).

If you're having a problem caused by sending a message to a deallocated instance, use the Zombies instrument in Instruments. It will tell you when you've messaged a deallocated object, allow you to see the offending call stack, along with the allocation/retain/release/dealloc history of the messaged object.

Under ARC, you shouldn't be thinking about exact object lifetimes so much as ownership semantics. That said, when you set a strong variable to nil under ARC, the referenced object is released. Whether or not it's deallocated (ie. "remove[s] itself from memory"), depends on whether any other objects have a strong reference to it. Also, if it's in any autorelease pools, it won't be deallocated until the pools drain (true under both ARC and MRC). Again, the details of what's going on in any particular case can be discovered using the Allocations instrument.